# ORA-01036 - illegal variable name/number

Tags: c#, oracle11g, dynamic-sql

I have a dynamic SQL for searching records in Oracle, and VS2017 code analysis reports warning about using parameterized SQL query for this line (1st line, this code works):

```
string SQL = "SELECT " + string.Join(",", my_columns.ToArray()) + " FROM MyTable ";
string where_condition = " WHERE ";

//the rest of code follows as this...
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text))
{
  SQL = string.Concat(SQL, where_condition, " Name like :name");
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("name", string.Concat("%", textbox1.Text, "%")));
  where_condition = " AND ";
} //...
```

So, I tried to put column names as parameters because of warning, but then I get ORA-01036- illegal variable name/number error:

```
 string SQL = "SELECT :columns FROM MyTable ";
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("columns", string.Join(",", 
 my_columns.ToArray())));
 string where_condition = " WHERE ";
```

What is wrong, maybe column names cannot be passed as parameters ? Or is there any other way to avoid warning in VS code analysis ?

Comment: As far as i know, you can't add column names as per parameter.

Comment: @Maciej Los,I was afraid of that. So there is nothing I can do to avoid warning in code analysis ?

Answer (score 0):

You're right - column names can't be passed as parameters. That part has to be done dynamically, unless you want to change your database structure very significantly. (You could have one column with a value which is the logical column name, and one column for the value. I'm *not* recommending this - it's very much not how databases are intended to be used.)

The warning you're getting is there to avoid SQL injection attacks. When building the query dynamically, you have to do that differently. You basically need to make sure you have a whitelist of column names, and only build up SQL including those names.

You may well still get a code analysis warning at that point, but you should disable that *just* for this piece of code, with a comment explaining that you understand the warning, and what you've done to remove the risk of SQL injection attacks.

Comment: thanks for response. But creating a whitelist - what did you mean by that ?...My column names are in array because user can select which columns to see in Datagridview, by selecting  checkboxes in application. Array stores their tags...

Comment: @Lucy82: I mean that you should have a list of valid column names, and make sure that whatever the user passes as the columns to use are valid column names. If this is a rich client GUI and the available columns are populated by the code it may not be as important, but if this is a web application and the column names are passed back from a browser, you should assume that the request could contain *anything* even if normal UI operation would only give valid names. It wouldn't hurt to check the column names in your database layer anyway, to make it more reusable.